# Getting Error in yammer search REST api

Tags: yammer

I've tried to get Yammer Seach results using yammer REST API I got only below error:

> `{“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}`

here is my code :

```
yam.platform.request({
          url: "search.json",
          method: "GET",
          data: {
              "search": "Test"
          },
          success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console
              alert("The request was successful.");
              console.dir(data);
          },
          error: function (err) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(err));                 
          }
      });
```

Comment: thats "jammer"as we call in holland, what means : that is a pitty

Comment: To render the code in your post readable, indent it by four spaces (or select the code and press control-K).